# C language boolean expression return value

Tags: c, boolean-expression

The C language does not have a Boolean datatype, using integers instead. Comparison
operators such as == and <= return the integer value 0 for false and 1 for true. However, the if statement in C considers any nonzero value of its condition to be equivalent to true. Why the difference? Why not allow the relational operators to return any nonzero value to represent true?

Comment: By making the relational operators return `0` and `1`, the language permits "shorthand calculations": `n += (n % 2 == 0); // increment n if it is even`; Also the language already takes any nonzero value to represent true: just use it directly in conditions without relational operators.

Comment: "return any nonzero value to represent true" -- what's to be gained by leaving it ambiguous?  Does it deliver more flexibility to implementers?  How could they capitalize on this flexibility?

Comment: C has had a Boolean datatype for the last 15 years: `_Bool` / `bool`, defined in `stdbool.h`.

Comment: C does have a Boolean type. It's called `_Bool` (aliased as `bool` if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`). It was added by the 1999 ISO C standard. But the comparison operators still yield `int` results.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based, especially viewing the discussion in the comments to various posts.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it was an arbitrary decision, going back to C's ancestor language B.

Quoting the [Users' Reference to B](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html):

> The relational operators `<` (less than), `<=` (less than or equal to), `>` (greater than), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) take integer rvalue operands. The result is one if the operands are in the given relation to one another. The result is zero otherwise.

No explanation is given of this particular choice, nor is it explained in the [ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html) or in the 1978 1st edition of Kernighan & Ritchie's book "The C Programming Language" (K&R1).

(B's ancestor language BCPL had `true` and `false` literals, with `true` being represented with all bits set to `1`.)

The language *could* have been defined differently, and it still would have been internally consistent. For example, the standard could have said that the relational and equality operators yield a result of `0` if the condition is false, or any arbitrary non-zero value if the condition is true. The result could still be used correctly in an `if` statement, or any other context requiring a condition. And it's easy to imagine a CPU on which it's more efficient for a true value to be represented as all-bits-one rather than as `1` -- but the language standard doesn't permit that.

Several standard library functions, such as `isdigit()`, may return any arbitrary non-zero value to indicate a true condition, which further demonstrates that this was an arbitrary choice. (`isdigit` is naturally implemented via a table lookup which can yield values other than `0` and `1`).

There is some added convenience in having the equality and relational operators yield `0` and `1`. For example, this makes it easy to keep a count of how many conditions are true:

```
int count = 0;
count += x == y;
count += foo > bar;
count += this <= that;
```

My guess is that it was convenient to use `0` and `1` in the first B compiler, the behavior was documented, and it's been inherited up until today. Changing the definition would have broken code that depended on the previous definition.

And even if it's relatively inefficient on some systems, it's not a huge problem. The result of an equality or relational operator is not usually stored anywhere, so a compiler can represent the result however it likes as long as the behavior is consistent. It might have to generate code to normalize the result to `0` or `1` in some cases, but that's not likely to be significant.

Answer (score 4):

If a conditional expression could return any nonzero value for true, you could get into trouble when storing it into too small variable, in the extreme case a one-bit bitfield.

```
struct foo { unsigned int bar: 1; } baz;
baz.bar = 1 == 1;
```

If the `1 == 1` conditional returned 2 (or any even number), you'de be in trouble as `baz.bar` would end up `0`, which evaluates as false in a boolean context.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a relational operator inside a conditional, the compiler is going to compile it into a "jump  if greater" or similar operator and wont bother actually computing the return value of the `<=` expression. It doesn't matter that the expression always return 0 or 1 because that value is never actually computed.

The only time where relational operators returning 0 or 1 will matter is when their value is used in a larger expression, like arithmetic or assigning to a variable. This is much less common than the situation of directly using them in a branch and the convenience of always returning 1 is not very costly.

Comment: `<` is not equivalent to subtraction. Suppose `x==INT_MAX` and `y==INT_MIN`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That is a good point. I was taking the SUB = CMP analogy a little too far.

Answer (score 0):

In C, 0 is false whether it's the return type from a comparison operator or an if statement, or whatever you want to check. However, while the if() statement will accept anything for true that isn't zero, the comparison operators *must return only one* object, and so it was decided that that object would be '1'. It's the difference between whether you're returning or accepting.

Just like in any other function, say `int foo(int x){}` you can accept *any* value of x, but you have to actually choose, before you leave the function, what you want to return. I suppose you could return a random number, but what good would that do? '1' was chosen instead.

Comment: Oh ... and why does `strcmp()` return **any** negative or positive value when strings are different? :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just returns the difference between str1 and str2, but not 100% positive.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's the not the question that was asked.

Comment: @ciphermagi: The C standard says only that `strcmp()` returns a negative, 0, or positive value. It needn't be the difference between anything -- though that's sometimes a convenient way to implement it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Stop intentionally misinterpreting things.

Comment: @ciphermagi: I believe that's exactly the question that was asked: "Why not allow the relational operators to return any nonzero value to represent true?"

Comment: @KeithThompson And I answered that question: Because a value had to be chosen, so they chose a value.

Comment: Any misinterpretation on my part is entirely unintentional. Be careful with accusations. A value has to be chosen either by the language standard or by an individual compiler. The question, as I see it, is why the language did not leave the decision up to each compiler, as it could have.

Comment: The whole point of what I said is that the function itself can't just arbitrarily decide some number. The programmer had to choose, at the time of creating the library which implemented the comparison operators, some sort of meaningful return value. Sure, he could have made it return a random value between 1 and the binary limit of the variable return type, but *what good would that do?*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49975/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-ciphermagi)